# Dynamic content accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website and I want to be able to access the dynamic content on the Menu page from every other page on the website but when you try to access it from another page, it doesn't even leave the page. How do I get it to take me to the Menu page and also display exactly what was clicked. The function created for this is as displayed below

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');
    });

      var _tagIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('#'); 
       if (_tagIndex>=0) {
           showContent(window.location.href.substr(_tagIndex));
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery [History plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) is a rather common solution